How to set up a firewall for an ubuntu network gateway
To get more experince with networking, I am creating a small virtual network within virtual box. PC 1 is an ubuntu install that has been configured to provide internet access to PC2, which is also an ubuntu PC.
PC1 has two NICs. One is used to connect to PC2 and the other to a router that allow internet access. I then manually configured the IP address settings via /etc/netplan/ for both devices so that PC1 would act as a gateway
All outbound traffic from PC2 must pass through PC1. I have confirmed this to function properly, as PC2 is only able to access any public IP address whenever PC1 is online.
I have been attempting to configure a firewall on PC1 for moderation of this virtual network via UFW. For testing purposes I blocked all connections to 8.8.8.8 using the following command: "sudo ufw deny from 8.8.8.8" . PC1 is now unable to ping 8.8.8.8 , however PC2 is still able to ping 8.8.8.8 . I have confirmed using wireshark that these pings are going through PC1 and their source is listed as 8.8.8.8
Is this a case of me using UFW for a purpose it is not intended, if so, please reccommend any alternatives

Please, add to your post the exact Ubuntu version from both PCs.

do you want to only configure just one firewall on PC1, which will  only act as firewall and gateway? Are you using Ubuntu Server or Desktop? Add to your post all the NICs configurations.

How to Set Up a Firewall with UFW on Ubuntu

How to install UFW and use it to set up a basic firewall

Linux UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) Configuration Made Easy

How to Configure Your Ubuntu Firewall with UFW and Set Firewall Rules
